# Element could not be located at (x,y): how to fix for a list of WebElements that need to be clicked one by one

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I've been assigned a project that requires me to take an input from an user, scrape a website for that input and store it in a database, and, on subsequent requests, rearrange all data saved in the database using machine learning, offering the user a selection of choices based on his past behaviour.

The website I have to scrape is TripAdvisor.it.

I am currently working on the web-scraping part, in particular, I am working on populating my database by getting a list of attractions from a page, and click on each of them separately so I can save all the data related to each attraction.

I constantly get the error "Unknown Error: Element  is not clickable at point (x,y);..."

I figured it may be a problem of the javascript not loading completely on the tripadvisor page, so I surveyed here on stackoverflow various possibilities and tried adding an explicit wait, but it doesn't work.
Other things I tried:

1. Thread.sleep(1000); I know it isn't a good practice to use it, especially in a for cycle, I just wanted to force the program to wait, but it didn't work. I actually used up to 3000 millisec.
2. a method that checks whether js has loaded completely on the webpage (I adapted some code I found here on stackExchange, as I'm not very knowledgeable on javascript). This gave a TimeOut Error, I'm not really sure what that means.
3. using the ExpectedCondition `.visibilityOf(WebElement elem);` instead of `.elementToBeClickable(WebElement elem);` since I realized that the `.getNumberOfElementsFound(driver, locator)` method actually finds all the 30 elements on the page. I still receive the same error of "Element could not be located at (x,y)..."

Here is the code that throws the exception:

```
...
    By locator = By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'attractions-attraction-overview-main-TopPOIs__name')]");

    int numberOfElementsFound = getNumberOfElementsFound(driver, locator);

    for (int pos = 0; pos < numberOfElementsFound; pos++) {

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(getElementWithIndex(driver, locator, pos))).click();
        ...
    }
```

And here is the complete message of the error:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (360, 14). Other element would receive the click: ...

[Here](https://www.tripadvisor.it/Attractions-g187895-Activities-Florence_Tuscany.html) is the link to the actual webpage I'm working on, if it's of any help.

Am I correct in my assessment that javascript is the culprit here? I concluded it may be that, because when I search for that tag "ui_column wrap_column responsive_inline_hidden label_column" on the actual page, I can't find it.

What should I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few causes for the **Other element would receive the click** error; but generally it is because something was added to the screen.

My first guess is that one of the dropdowns from the top nav is being triggered causing an overlay on top of what you're trying to click.

I noticed that when I hover over "Firenze" in the top nav, the dropdown covers part of the "Gite di un giorno" image. So if the automation thinks the cursor is over the "Firenze" when you load the page, the dropdown will appear and the automation would click the dropdown instead of the image causing the error message.

If that is the case, you should do what I call a "clickOut" method prior to clicking on any of the links. A "clickOut" is a throwaway method that just clicks on the `<body>` tag. They are useful when there are popups on the screen that go away if you click outside of the popup. But in this case, it would virtually move the cursor and cause any of the dropdowns to go away.

It's a long shot, but I have seen it a number of times in building tests.